# Benchmarking EM Soft Clustering vs K-Means?

Tags: cluster-analysis, benchmarking, k-means, data-mining, expectation-maximization

I have two implementations one is K-Means and the other is EM doing soft clustering. But I do not know how to validate them in terms of accuracy. i.e. which one performs better by retrieving better clusters.
My assumption is that because EM is doing soft assignments instead of hard ones as it happens in K-Means. EM performs better, but I do not know how to do this comparison...

How can I benchmark the accuracy of EM soft clustering vs K-Means? 
and also any suggestions for the synthetic data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Evaluating fuzzy clustering is itself hard. I believe i have seen some variation of one of the common indexes somewhere.

But first try to answer this question:

### When is one clustering algorithm better than the other?

Clustering algorithms are supposed to be an explanatory tool, so can you really judge the performance on synthetic, labeled data at all? Or souldn't you measure quality by going out to the "field" and trying to learn something new from data?

This is not a math problem.

EM, because of its fuzzy assignments, should be less likely to get stuck in a local minima than k-means. At least in theory. At the same time, it never converges. Lloyds k-means must converge (with squared Euclidean, not with other distances) because of a finiteness argument; the same argument does not hold for fuzzy algorithms anymore.

Maybe try constructing a scenario where k-means does not yield the opimal solution, and then check if EM yields better results.

Comment: Thanks a lot Anony-Mousse! just, how can I make sure about your last statement? "To build a scenario where K-Means does not yield the optimal solution?"
At the moment, I will create maybe 2000 datapoints with 2 dimensions, using the same centroids and see which one gives me better results after 3 iterations...

Comment: You need to carefully engineer the distribution of the data points and seeds to deliberately misdirect k-means in 2D synthetic data. Just randomly generating data won't do the trick.

Comment: Ok great, thanks! so... Do you mean to create data like in this image: http://dovgalecs.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2012/11/untitled.jpg ?
Also, I think I can compare the stopping conditions of both to check the accuracy right? i.e. For K-Means the MSE and for the EM, the new values of the clusters and SD - the old clusters and old SD values

Comment: That data set is probably still feasible enough for k-means; but it may depend on your starting conditions. Don't compare these SD to the MSE values; it is not a fair comparison.

Comment: Hello! Yes I thought the same... What could be a fair comparison? Because I do not know if I can retrieve the MSE from the EM algorithm... that's why I wanted to compare the stopping conditions of each algorithm...

Comment: I don't think there is a fair comparison possible based just on mathematics. Only on practical use on real data.
Stopping conditions of EM are not even consistent across implementations; nor is the computation of the SD value.

Comment: Hello Anony! then... do you think is possible to compute the MSE for the EM soft-clustering just like we do in K-Means? this way I can compare both MSE: The one of K-Means and the one of EM.

Comment: It will still be unfair. k-means sole purpose is to find a MSE minimum. Any method will look bad compared to k-means, if you compare it by MSE. It's like evaluating orange trees by their ability to produce apples. They'll never produce as good apples as apple trees.

Comment: In my opinion, there is **no objective quality criterion**. For every criterion, there actually exists a way to construct an optimal algorithm (exhaustive search). It's just very slow. So to some extend, the criterion is an algorithm, too. This is actually well-known for k-means: finding the optimal k-means (=minimizing MSE) is an NP-hard problem. Lloyds algorithm is an O(n*k*i) approximation to this. It will not always find the best solution, but it's acceptably fast.

Comment: Thanks a lot for all your explanation! then... I think I will just plot the graphs of the final clusters of EM soft-Clustering and K-Means. Using the same clusters initialization and same number of iterations and create a synthetic data like the one of the image: dovgalecs.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2012/11/untitled.jpg so I do not create totally random data.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the silhouette score to measure the effectiveness of your clustering algorithms. 
http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.silhouette_score.html

From the documentation: *The Silhouette Coefficient is calculated using the mean intra-cluster distance (a) and the mean nearest-cluster distance (b) for each sample. The Silhouette Coefficient for a sample is (b - a) / max(a, b). To clarify, b is the distance between a sample and the nearest cluster that the sample is not a part of.*

In simpler terms, Silhouette coefficients measure how close points are to their given center compared to other potential centers. You can use these scores to determine which clustering algorithm leads to points being closer to one another, or also which parameters lead to higher silhouette coefficients (eg. the number of clusters). Examples are given for K-Means algorithms at the bottom as well.